# Rename worksheet Based on INPUT BOX

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me to to change the below code. Need to select the renaming cell through `InputBox`

Thanks

```
Sub RenWSs()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim shtName
Dim newName As String
Dim i As Integer

For Each WS In Worksheets
    With WS
        If Trim(.Range("c14")) <> "" Then
            shtName = Split(Trim(.Range("c14")), " ")
            newName = shtName(0)
            On Error GoTo ws_name_error
            .Name = newName
            GoTo done
repeat:
            .Name = newName & i
            GoTo done
ws_name_error:
            i = i + 1
            Resume repeat
        End If
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
done:
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you want to Use `InputBox` for what ? to enter the cell's address, like "C4" ?  or to enter the new name of the current scheet ?

Comment: to enter the cell "C4" cell

Comment: see my answer below for two methods of using the `InputBox` to select the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can use the `InputBox` to access Cell C4.

One is by selecting a `String` in the `InputBox` , see code below:

```
Dim RngStr  As String

RngStr = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Cell for the new Sheet's name", Type:=2)
If Trim(.Range(RngStr)) <> "" Then
```

---

Another, is by selecting a `Range` in the `InputBox`, see code below:

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Cell for the new Sheet's name", Type:=8)
If Trim(rng) <> "" Then
```

---

### Full Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenWSs()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim shtName
Dim newName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim RngStr  As String

RngStr = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Range for the new Sheet's name", Type:=2)
For Each WS In Worksheets
    With WS        
        If Trim(.Range(RngStr)) <> "" Then
            shtName = Split(Trim(.Range(RngStr)), " ")
            newName = shtName(0)
            On Error GoTo ws_name_error
            .Name = newName
            GoTo done
repeat:
            .Name = newName & i
            GoTo done
ws_name_error:
            i = i + 1
            Resume repeat
        End If
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
done:

Next

End Sub
```

---

To read more about `InputBox` functionality: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think 1st one is okay since i am not selecting the name by range, i am calling particular cell for rename( The New Name is already available in subject cell). can u tell me where i have to paste exactly in your code

Comment: Thanks, but the input box is asking new name for every sheet. I need to input once to change all the worksheets, please help

Comment: @ayyappankm I just took it out of the `For` loop, try now

Comment: Sorry i am new to this, please advise how to mark as answer

Comment: @ayyappankm put a little **V** next to my answer post

Comment: And if possible please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781772/hfm-smartview-refresh. it would be more helpful for me. Once Again Thanks

Comment: Hi can u please do one more help, instead of split and trim, i need to take full cell content for new name(like maximum length allowed by excel)

Comment: @ayyappankm if you try `.Name = .Range(RngStr)` , is it working ?

Comment: @ Shadi Rado Great Thanks............................................ Working Fine

Comment: I am seeking your Help,  please answer my question Stackoverflow.com/questions/40781772/hfm-smartview-refresh. it would be more helpful for me. Once Again Thanks for your support.

Comment: @ayyappankm I am not familiar with `SmartView` , trying to research it, it seems my company has disabeld this feature in our Excel

Comment: its excel macro only, currently the code selecting all worksheets and calling hypmenuvrefresh, my requirement is from active workbook need to call hypmenuvrefersh than go to next worksheet again call hypmenuvrefersh like this for end of all sheets, i think the changes to be done here ********o While i <= Count
             
        If Worksheets(i).Name <> "POV" Then
    
    Worksheets(i).Select
      
      HypMenuVRefresh

End If
                    
             i = i + 1

Comment: i have drop down list, with 40 rows, from the drop down list i need to update one by one in 40 worksheet in row j16, is it possible to include the above code, Please help

Comment: I must apologize, but this is not the way SO works. You should open another post with your request/problem, and add to it your latest code

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, i have raised separate question, if possible please help me sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886963/rename-worksheet-with-dropdown-list