# Rename Worksheet with Dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to rename worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenWSs()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shtName
    Dim newName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RngStr  As String

    RngStr = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the Range for the new Sheet's name", Type:=2)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            If Trim(.Range(RngStr)) <> "" Then
                shtName = Split(Trim(.Range(RngStr)), " ")
                newName = shtName(0)
                On Error GoTo ws_name_error
                .Name = .Range(RngStr)
                GoTo done
repeat:
                .Name = newName & i
                GoTo done
ws_name_error:
                i = i + 1
                Resume repeat
            End If
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
done:
    Next

End Sub
```

In this i am selecting the new name through Input Box and its working fine. Now what i want is, before calling the input box, the below process has to be done.

I have names in drop down list, each names in drop down list to be updated one by one in all worksheets like J16 is the cell.

Please help me

Comment: I don't understand, what and where are your drop-down lost ? you have a drop-down in cell "J16" in every sheet ?

Comment: yes i have drop down list in cell j16 in each sheet

Comment: what is the source or value that these dron down should have?

Comment: Source is in E1 to E10,

Comment: I am not sure what needs to be done here ??? are these drop-downs already defined in each sheet ? if they are why do you need to update them by code ?

Comment: This code should select names one by one and update in each sheet- cell J16, actualy i have 40 names and 40 worksheet, instead of selecting manually i am asking through codes. In drop down list 40 names available that one by one to be updated from active sheet to last sheet. please help

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand anything. I realy don't understand the concept and logics of what you are trying to achieve. You need to edit your post here, and explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sir, i need to input company name in Cell J16 for 40 Worksheet. I have the list of companies in some other rows, so i have made drop down list in cell j16, currently i will select the names in each sheet through drop down list for 40 worksheets. instead of doing this manually i am asking to do by code. the data which was selected through in drop down list is also my worksheet name, that i will change through the above code. So i am combining this 2 process.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will lopp through all `ws` sheets, and modifies the value of cell in "J16" to "Test 1" (just for testing purposes).

```
Option Explicit


Sub ModifyDropDownValue()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        ' modify the value in cell J16
        .Range("J16").Value = "Test 1"
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, its working fine, but i need to update the companies names in 40 worksheet, (Name will be different), instead of putting Test1, how do i select from drop down list like drop down name 1, drop down name 2...........